# Opera text marker addon?

Tags: browser-addons, opera

Is there an add-on for Opera similar to Firefox's [TextMarker!](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/textmarker/) or [TextMarker Go](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/textmarker-go/)?

These markers allow you to arbitrarily mark pieces of text with pre-defined colors, which is extremely useful for task lists, checklists or the likes: you can easily mark an item like passed/failed etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the name is [Highlighter](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/highlighter/):

Description from the home page:

> With this extension you can highlight elements on the webpage. Basicly it works like
>   a highlighter pen, but it's more complex. You can highlight any number of elements
>   including sections of text and tables and areas on images.

Usage:

- press hotkey and mouse button and draw the rectangle
- click on a rectangle to destroy.

Comment: `This extension is only supported in Opera 11 and 12.`